# Chopstick repair?

Tags: wood-repair

I have a nice pair of custom red wooden (cedar maybe?) chopsticks I took home as a gift from an event last year and about one inch completely broke off of one.

I have both pieces, as it was a clean break. What is the best way to repair it so that I can continue to use it and still maintain some sort of strength/integrity?

Comment: I'm a little late to the party, as there's already an accepted answer, but I think there is a pretty big question here as to how it broke.  Did it break along a natural defect in the wood?  Was the grain runout?  Or did it break in an otherwise normal spot?

Comment: Just want to reinforce two things that @SaSSafraS1232 has brought up. Where the break occurred is quite a critical thing here (to understand why it broke in the first place but both also to know the grain orientation you'll be dealing with within the glued joint) and second, while Titebond III is excellent glue and will be waterproof enough for this I'm sure it requires high (very high) clamp pressure for maximum strength, as covered in a few previous Answers here.

Comment: If the break occurred diagonally because of grain runout this in effect created a long scarf joint. If the wood inside is clean then glue and proper clamping should be fine, scarf joints are very strong. However if the wood inside is not clean and/or the break doesn't come together perfectly then you should probably use epoxy. But if the snap is what I would term a splintery break (like what you usually see if you snap a pencil in two) none of this applies, no glue will give you a strong join by itself and you **must** reinforce some way, e.g. by drilling for a reinforcing rod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If can you properly orient the broken ends together, use a two-part epoxy adhesive.

This one will cure a room temperature without needing any extraordinary clamping.
[Food-safe, two-part epoxy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01DJC3FNE)

Comment: great! Thank you for this recommendation. I will use this as a starting point.